# Creating a favorite list in rails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i have a problem to solve in my application here a little brief:
My app is something like AirBnb so i have `Users` and `Houses`, any user can create a house i already have this,  i need a watch list, is a list of houses who user liked like a Bookmark or Favorite system, i have the house list and the idea is have button like "watch this" when user clicks this house go to their watch lists.
I've seen many solutions and i tried them, i understand the relationship but i don't know how do get pieces in.
here is my code currently:

`watch.rb:`

```
class Watch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house
end
```

`user.rb:`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :houses, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :watches, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :watch_houses, :through => :watches, :source => :houses
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

`house.rb:`

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
    has_many   :watches, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many   :watches, :through => :watches, :source => :user
end
```

`routes.rb:`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :houses
    devise_for :users
    resources :users, :only => [:show] do
        resources :watches
    end
    resources :houses
    root 'home#index'
end
```

How can i create a link to assing the user and the house in the watchlist cliking in the house list?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :houses do
   post :watch #-> url.com/houses/:house_id/watch
end

#app/controllers/houses_controller.rb
class HousesController < ApplicationController
   def watch
      @house = House.find params[:house_id]
      current_user.watched_houses << @house
      redirect_to @house, notice: "Added to Watch List"
   end
end
```

Here are the models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :watching, class_name: "Watch", foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :watched_houses, through: :watching
end

#app/models/house.rb
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :watches, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :watchers, through: :watches, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Comment: Thank you!, but now i create the lik to watch the house `<td><%= link_to 'Watch', house_watch_path(house), method: :post %></td>` but i'm getting this error `Could not find the source association(s) "watched_house" or :watched_houses in model Watch. Try 'has_many :watched_houses, :through => :watching, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or house?` do you know that?